# Triangle Inequality Property for the Euclidean Metric

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces, triangles

I've read in many of my books that the triangle inequality for a metric space of the Euclidean Metric is defined as:

$$d(x,y) \leq d(x,z) + d(z,y)$$

But when I look up the proof, to help me understand it, many if not all the proofs go about it this way:

$$d(x,y)+d(y,z) \geq d(x,z)$$

I do not understand why they go about it this way, instead of by the definition. What am I missing?

I am using this definition of Euclidean Metric http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EuclideanMetric.html

Comment: Interchange $y$ and $z.$

Comment: @Nilan why are we simply allowed to interchange them?

Comment: They are jest names for points in that space. So, you can give any name for a point as you like.

Comment: Oh wow, now I see. They are using different names. Such a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is same in the substance, although they are different in the form.
The following picture may be helpful for you to understand the triangle inequality.

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain to me how they are the same, or how  one would go by changing the first into the second? I am having a lot of trouble.

Comment: @Frumpy I have added a picture to help you understand the triangle inequality.